Не могу сделать регистрацию с буквенным ником, с цифрами проблемы не возникает
Код для поиска вводимых данных (ник, пароль, почта) в таблице users в столбце name выглядит так
check_query = f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name COLLATE utf8mb4_bin = {nick_name};"
cursor.execute(check_query)
records = cursor.fetchall()

Ошибка выглядит так
(1054, "Unknown column 'uu' in 'where clause'")

Скрин таблицы приложил
Если ввожу буквы (в данном случае "з") - не мешает при добавлении буквы и в пароль и в почту, а на name почему-то ругается
Латинские тоже пробовал - одинаковая ошибка


Попробуйте посмотреть, что получилось в check_query

SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = abc; (1054, "Unknown column 'ss' in 'where clause'")

Как говорится, "не верю". Было бы "Unknown column 'abc' in 'where clause'" - я б поверил, а сейчас стопроцентно текст ошибки не соответствует тексту запроса. А по поводу упоротого косяка - читайте https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html

Вот и я логику тоже понять не могу, спасибо за ссылку сейчас прочту

Да, проблемы были в кавычках как писал автор выше, разобраться помогла эта статья
https://bobcares.com/blog/mysql-error-code-1054/#:~:text=MySQL%20error%20code%201054%20occurs,due%20to%20any%20missing%20column.
В итоге я окружил переменную одинарными кавычками и всё стало ок
check_query = f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '{nick_name}';"


не используй шаблоны в sql запросах. используй передачу параметров!

Можно плиз пример или ссылку на то как надо ?
